# Adding and finding classes that is dynamically added to body - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic

Is there any way to add classes or alter objects that is dynamically added to the body?

I am adding a range of objects to the body by javascript. 
Fot instance Im adding some links that is dynamically generated and added to the body. When they are loaded I need to elect the first of the divs and add a new class to it.

I can't seem to find any way to do this... Update the DOM or how should I go around this? There must be a way to alter dynamically added objects.

Any clues?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you want this done automatically when you add the items or can you run some code after adding them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you added them dynamically, then you can just use the objects you already have. Otherwise you'll need to find them with sizzle.

```
//create the elements
var $link1 = $('<a>click me</a>').attr('href','page1.html');
var $link2 = $('<a>click me</a>').attr('href','page2.html');

//append the elements
$('#some-links').append($link1).append($link2);

//use the element we created
$link1.addClass('my-class');

//find the second link element using sizzle
$('#some-links>a').eq(1).addClass('my-other-class');
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PtebM/2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This would work but I am adding the links dynamic with a for loop. From my understanding theses links are only added to the documentt dynamic the javascript declares them inside the javascript not dynamic.

Comment: My for loop looks like this and fetches the category from a xml  for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        
         //gets the category
         var cat = categories[i].getAttribute("cat");
         
         
         //creates the html link list
         linkList = "<a href='#' class='catPassive' id='id_"+cat+"' onclick=\"javascript:showMarker('"+cat+"');\">"+cat+"</a>";
         //array
         catListArr.push(linkList);
         //add the link list 
         $('#selectorList').append(linkList);
         
        }

Comment: Got it working finally! I added a delay to the eq so that all elements get the chance to be added before we try to find them. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well of course you caN:

```
var a = $('<a>');
a.html('new link').appendTo('#menu');
a.addClass('border');
```

or

```
var a = $('<a>');
a.html('new link').appendTo('#menu');
$('#menu a').addClass('border');
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4NPqH/

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a class name to your generated elements?.

I.e.:

`$('span').html('Hello world').addClass("fancyText").appendTo('body');`